# XmlHttpContent serializer sort fileds alphabetically

Tags: java, xml

I need strict compliance with the order of the elements in my xml document. If I use XmlHttpContent serializer to form xml content, fields sort alphabetically.

Is there any way to specify explicitly order of the elements in xml? Or are there other ways to create and post http requests with the xml body?

Comment: order of elements and attributes is guaranteed by the XML specifications, if you need a specific order you need to provide an ordinal that you can sort the parsed results by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer isn't ideal but I recently came across this issue when trying to use the http client library for serialisation to xml. The solution I've found that works is to have my DTO classes provide a method to convert them into a sorted map of some kind.

In my case this is an `ImmutableMap<String, Object>` as I'm also using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) but any map with controllable order will do. The basic idea is to work with the java objects to construct your data but then when the time comes to serialise them you serialise the map instead.

```
public interface OrderedXml {
  ImmutableMap<String, Object> toOrderedMap();
}

public class Parent implements OrderedXml {
  @Key("First") String first;
  @Key("Second") String second;
  @Key("Child") Child third;

  @Override
  public ImmutableMap<String, Object> toOrderedMap() {
    return ImmutableMap.of(
      // the order of elements in this map will be the order they are serialised
      "First", first,
      "Second", second,
      "Child", third.toOrderedMap()
    );
  }
}

public class Child implements OrderedXml {
  @Key("@param1") String param1;
  @Key("@param2") String param2;
  @Key("text()") String value;

  @Override
  public ImmutableMap<String, Object> toOrderedMap() {
    return ImmutableMap.of(
      // the same goes for attributes, these will appear in this order
      "@param1", param1,
      "@param2", param2,
      "text()", value
    );
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // make the objects
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.first = "Hello";
    parent.second = "World";
    parent.child = new Child();
    parent.child.param1 = "p1";
    parent.child.param2 = "p2";
    parent.child.value = "This is a child";
    // serialise the object to xml
    String xml = new XmlNamespaceDictionary()
        .toStringOf("Parent", parent.toOrderedXml()); // the important part
    System.out.println(xml); // should have the correct order
  }
}
```

I know this solution isn't ideal but at least you can reuse the `toOrderedXml` to make a nice `toString` :-).